# Are there any resources for recipes from the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, food

The Star Trek universe has many displays or references to some exotic and interesting foods from alien cultures.

Some interesting examples include:

- [Hasperat](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hasparat)
- [Niccel Strips](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Niccel_strips)
- [Chech'tluth](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Chech%27tluth)

And who can forget classics like...

- [Gagh](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gagh)
- [Saurian Brandy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Saurian_brandy)
- [Romulan Ale](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Romulan_ale)
- [Bloodwine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bloodwine)

Are there any resources, online or otherwise, which have recipes for real-world versions of some of the alien dishes featured in the Star Trek universe?  I'm especially interested in production notes describing how the dishes were prepared for use on-stage, but fan-created or official derivative recipe books would be good to see as well.

Comment: If there is one site I didn't expect this one to overlap with, it'd be [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/). Great :)

Comment: I see TOS and VOY covered in two answers here.  Any chance there's books for TNG & DS9?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Star Trek Cooking Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553118196) is described as:

> The recipes are generally for Terran ethnic food, albeit in some cases tweaked a bit to suggest non-Terran cultures.
>
> The Klingon section is quite different from Klingon cuisine as presented in canonical sources; it also includes a description (but not a recipe) for a gelatin dish with bits of exceptionally pungent cheese floating in it, covered with a sauce described as resembling mint-flavored milk of magnesia.

The [Star Trek Cookbook](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e8ce/) has the following description:

> The favorite foods of characters from every Star Trek series and movie are here, all adapted for easy use in twentieth-century kitchens. The Star Trek Cookbook also features a complete guide for whipping up all the drinks served at Quark's.

These are the only two official cookbooks relating to the Star Trek universe.

There are a number of one-off receipes on the internet for people who invented their own versions for the more popular foods mentioned on the show, particularly Klingon. Here are a few examples:

- [K'Tesh's Klingon Recipe Pages](http://www.geocities.ws/ktesh_kag/recipes2.htm)
- [Klingon Drinks: A List of Recipes](http://www.klingon.org/smboard/index.php?topic=1287.0;wap2)
- [Aaktay Klingon Steamed Bread](http://www.rhubarbinfo.com/startrek)

Comment: Is there any particular reference you're using to state that the Star Trek Cookbook and Cooking Manual are the only two official ones, or is this just by reasonable inference from a thorough search?  I'd be a bit disappointed if there wasn't a book for the TNG era.

Comment: And, holey smokes... a *GeoCities* page?  I didn't even realize they were still around!

Comment: *Fourteen* recipes for Bloodwine at that drinks page - wow!  Great resources, here!

Comment: @Iszi Looking through various book retailers those are the only two that ever come up. Additionally Memory-Alpha doesn't have any others listed (and they would know). http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Category:Reference_books

Comment: @Iszi In 2009 Yahoo shutdown geocities, but I guess there is a [geocities.ws](http://geocities.ws) project to save all those *precious* webpages.

Comment: I'm not to sure about that Klingon Drinks link... something tells me a Raktajino is stronger than light and sweet coffee with an ounce of vanilla...

Answer (score 8):

There's the:

[image: Official Star Trek Cooking Manual]

The author's name -- and this is no joke -- is actually *Piccard*.

Answer (score 6):

My wife has cooked some of the recipes from the [Star Trek Cookbook](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e8ce/). Sisko's chicken is pretty good.

[image]

Comment: It's *Sisko*, not Sisqo.  [Benjamin Sisko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Sisko) was a Starfleet captain in the 24th century, and most well known for being commander of Deep Space 9 among other things.  [Sisqo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisqo) was a rapper in the 20th & 21st centuries, and is most well known for his *Thong Song* among other things.  FTFY

Comment: @Iszi - LOL. Thank you. I suppose you'll be telling me Dark Vader's laser sword isn't red next.  ;-) (My kid goes nuts when I say that to him.  "It's DARTH Vader's LIGHTBABER!, Dad!!!")

Answer (score 4):

There are some people on Youtube called [Feastoffiction](http://www.youtube.com/user/feastoffiction).  They make food mentioned in various tv shows, books and movies, and seem to lean towards science fiction & fantasy themes.  They take suggestions from viewers, so you might be able to ask them to do a recipe for you.  They film themselves making the food so it's really easy to do yourself.